# Why does video appear rotated on external monitor?

Tags: safari

Safari, when the mouse pointer is outside the external screen the video is on.

M1 with two monitors via HDMI, Safari Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12), macOS 13.0.1 (22A400).
[image]